# How to use jQuery plugins with Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a laravel app, where I have vue components, and in one of them I am trying to use input field for which I want to use [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput), to make masked inputs. I have a main app.js file where I import all other files:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./slider');
require('./search-form');
require('./scroll-spy');
require('./smooth-scroll');
require('./autocomplete');
require('./jquery.maskedinput');
require('./form-mask');
```

And this is how I am trying to make my input masked in `form-mask` file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[data-mask='date']").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

And this is the field in the vue component:

```
<input type="text" data-mask="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="info-data-input">
```

But, I get an error:

> $(...).mask is not a function

Why is that, and how can I use that plugin inside my vue components?

Comment: Are you importing jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I am using cdn for jQuery slim.

Comment: Did you ensure that the jQuery and jQuery plugin script tags come before the script tag that utilizes them? Can you make a [mcve]?